# jQuery : how to manipulate indexes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should not be such a hard question... I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to make operations on some jquery elements, particularly their indexes. Teh codez:

```
$( "#docSlider" ).css("background-image", "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" + $( "#selectable li" ).index( this ) + (".jpg)"));
```

I want to make the name of the picture I load depend on the index of a jQuery selectable. So I grab the index and try to add 1... but it can't work because "+" is also a concatenator.
I've tried to parseInt as well, but it was always worth 0.

How do I simply transform the index to an integer and then concatenate it with the rest of the string?

Thank you in advance!

Edit : I'm using a function that already exists, so I can hardly change the parameters (well, I guess I can't...)

I have this sample of code in my $(function() {}) section :

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
                selected: function(event, ui) { 
                    $( "#docSlider" ).css("background-image", $( "#selectable li" ).index( this ) "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" +  + (".jpg)"));
                }});

//initalizing
                $( "#docSlider" ).css("background-image",  "url(../../bundles/auraeconference/images/maquette/img" + $( "#selectable li" ).index( this ) + (".jpg)"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like

```
$( "#docSlider" ).css("background-image",function(i){
          return "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img"+ (i+1)+".jpg";
});
```

[`$.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) has an alternate syntax like

```
 .css( propertyName, function(index, value) )
```

You can make use of that.

**UPDATE**

`this` inside the `selectable` callback, in your case refers to `#selectable` . So you can either use

```
$(this).find('li').index(ui.selected);
```

or

```
$( "#selectable li" ).index( ui.selected )
```

so you can try this

```
selected: function(event, ui) { 
      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( ui.selected ) + 1;
     $( "#docSlider" )
          .css("background-image",  "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" + index + ".jpg)");
                }});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/kuAhv/30/)

Comment: @TheSystemRestart I wrote this myself and saw an answer was posted while writing. and posted that. Cant two answer be the same?

Comment: Seems interesting, but how do I declare and use the function at the same time in the css syntax?

Comment: Use this for the whole container, not just an individual item with `id`.Like `$('.container').css('background-image',function(i){..})` then jQuery will call that function for each element and set their background image based on their indexes.

Comment: I don't picture at all how to do that... How do I declare the function? If it's simply function(index, value) then where do I really give it my index? If not what do I use the index for, and how do I retrieve the parameter inside the function?

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to get each element its own background. I want to change the background of another element (always the same) according to the index of the currently selected element.

Comment: But seriously, isn't there a simple way to make an addition in the middle of a string concatenation???

Comment: Thank you. As I said on the other answer, now I have another problem, the index that I'm returned is always -1. But your post answers the question, thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your minimal html structure too?

Comment: Actually it's okay, I completely changed it and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#docSlider" ).css("background-image", function(index, url) {
   return "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" + (index + 1) + (".jpg)");
});
```

`.css()` take property and handler also as parameter, so you don't need to worry about that function, this will not effect your code or existing function.

According to you edit

```
$ "#selectable" )
          .selectable({
             selected: function(event, ui) { 
               var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( ui.selected ) + 1;
               $( "#docSlider" )
                   .css("background-image", function(){ 
                         return "url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" +  index + (".jpg)")});
                }});
```

or simply

```
$( "#docSlider" )
          .css("background-image","url(../../bundles/mypath/images/maquette/img" +  index + (".jpg)")});
```

Comment: I've updated my question... I'm afraid I can't change the function's parameters

Comment: @GabrielTheron where is you function? post that

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I have another problem now, but this is what I was looking for, thanks!